# How can I beat the level "Square"?

Tags: super-sanctum-td

What is the best maze setup in *Super Sanctum TD* on the level "Square"?  I tried different mazes with no success.

Comment: related (but not sure if dupe as the related is much broader) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/optimum-mazing-path-by-length

Comment: Best maze in what manner?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Presumably the question he wants to ask (which is on-topic) is "How do I beat the level 'Square'"

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the image below, the "secret" that I discovered is about the same for almost every level: a long maze.

[image: Violators winning, not perfect.]

I did not know well enough the level so the entrance is not in the ideal spot, I believe the maze should be rotated 90°/180° to the right as the most dangerous monsters come from the top-left spawn point, even the boss of wave 10.

Here the perks used:
[image: Perks.]

Instead of using the Kairos I used the slowing panels on the floor, they slow much less and in a smaller zone, but I found them very helpful in the initial stage (I lost core health because the maze was not rotated enough so the dangerous monsters took less damage than expected).

I wanted to use the tower booster (number 4), but I found more secure (from my point of view) to use an additional Violator instead to maximize the pressure on the monster that was leading in the maze (pointed all the towers to the first monster).

If anyone have a better suggestion (mainly aiming for 10 perfect waves), please let me know, I'll update the answer if I find the way to have a perfect run.

Meanwhile, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

i used a very similar maze setup, but only used amp fields, kairos, flashes and lightnings. positioned so that the monster go two times through a "hot spot" with a lot of free walkin inbetween. perks all into energy weapons of course. upgrade kairo first. then a second one. then all the lightnings. makes the monsters veeeeery slow in the amp field area. placed alot of mines towards the end of the path, what finally killed the boss. the only monster that could have made problems. this worked for a perfect run the first try.

Answer (score 0):

get lots of voilators, a couple of flashes, and 4 kairos. For power ups I used both mines, bomb and thunderbolt which I used to focus down the mutators as soon as they spawned.